# Volatile arrays and memory barriers and visibility in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, memory-barriers

I am having difficulties understanding memory barriers and cache coherence in Java, and how these concepts relate to arrays.

I have the following scenario, where one thread modifies an array (both the reference to it and one of its internal values) and another thread reads from it.

```
int[] integers;
volatile boolean memoryBarrier;

public void resizeAndAddLast(int value) {
    integers = Arrays.copyOf(integers, integers.size + 1);
    integers[integers.size - 1] = value;
    memoryBarrier = true;
}

public int read(int index) {
    boolean memoryBarrier = this.memoryBarrier;
    return integers[index];
}
```

My question is, does this do what I think it does, i.e. does "publishing" to `memoryBarrier` and subsequently reading the variable force a cache-coherence action and make sure that the reader thread will indeed get **both** the latest array reference and the correct underlying value at the specified index?

My understanding is that the array reference does not have to be declared `volatile`, it should be enough to force a cache-coherence action using **any** volatile field. Is this reasoning correct?

EDIT: there is precisely one writer thread and many reader threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, your code is thread-unsafe. A variation which would make it safe is as follows:

```
void raiseFlag() {
   if (memoryBarrier == true)
     throw new IllegalStateException("Flag already raised");
   memoryBarrier = true;
}

public int read(int index) {
  if (memoryBarrier == false)
     throw IllegalStateException("Flag not raised yet");
  return integers[index];
}
```

You only get to raise the flag once and you don't get to publish more than one `integers` array. This would be quite useless for your use case, though.

Now, as to the *why*... You do not guarantee that between the first and second line of `read()` there wasn't an intervening write to `integers` which was observed by the second line. The lack of a memory barrier does not *prevent* another thread from observing an action. It makes the result unspecified.

There is a simple idiom that would make your code thread-safe (specialized for the assumption that a single thread calls `resizeAndAddLast`, otherwise more code is necessary and an `AtomicReference`):

```
volatile int[] integers;

public void resizeAndAddLast(int value) {
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(integers, integers.length + 1);
    copy[copy.length - 1] = value;
    integers = copy;
}

public int read(int index) {
    return integers[index];
}
```

In this code you never touch an array once it got published, therefore whatever you dereference from `read` will be observed as intended, with the index updated.

Comment: My scenario is very specific and I can't get into details, but I actually do not need thread safety in the classical sense, because the reader thread would never be even able to request an index that was not previously published to the array. What happens is this: the reader always knows the maximum index available, but it doesn't know the underlying value at that index. Will my code guarantee that the reader always gets **both** the latest array reference **and** the underlying value at that index (instead of stale values)? It's an issue of visibility, not thread safety per se.

Comment: Not sure what's your distinction between visibility and thread safety; usually non-guaranteed visibility counts as thread-unsafety and vice versa. Your program contains a race as I described, which means that you are not guaranteed to observe both the latest array reference and the value at the index. I'm adding more code to show you the correct idiom for safe publication.

Comment: Oops... another answer already did that. He even decided to use the same var name :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated example. I've noticed that you removed the memory barrier field and declared the array itself volatile. If we were doing this with multiple arrays, instead of declaring every single array as volatile (volatile writes are expensive), could we simply process them as normal and then simply write to a single volatile field to ensure visibility propagation?

Comment: No, that would be as broken as your original code. You can remove the cost of a volatile write by using an `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` and calling `lazySet` instead. This preserves the write ordering guarantees.

Comment: Another approach is having an array of arrays, or any other holder object for all your arrays, and publishing that holder object with all the arrays updated.

Comment: @maxim1, _Thread safety in the classical sense_ is a lie.  You either can prove that your program will always do the right thing, or you can't.  Whenever somebody says, "Class `X` is thread safe."  They're saying it's guaranteed to behave in some particular way, but they're omitting the details of that guarantee.  "Thread safe" means different things in different contexts, and it can mean different things to different developers.  Always ask, "what are the actual guarantees?" and remember that building a program out of thread-safe objects won't necessarily make the whole program thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why it wont work in general:

- Java doesnt say anything about memory barriers or about the ordering
  of **unrelated** variables. Global Memory barriers is a side effect of
  x86
- Even with global memory barriers: The write-order of array-reference and indexed array-value is undefined. It is guarantied that both happen-before the memory barrier, but in which order? An unsynchronized read may see the reference but not the array-value. Your read-barrier doesnt help here in case of multiple read/writes.
- Beware of arrays of references: Visibility of referenced values requires special attention

A slightly better approach would be to declare the array itself as volatile **and** treat its values as immutable:

```
volatile int[] integers; // volatile (or maybe better AtomicReference)

public void resizeAndAddLast(int value) {
    // enforce exactly one volatile read!
    int[] copy = integers;
    copy = Arrays.copyOf(copy, copy.size + 1);
    copy[copy.size - 1] = value; 
    // may lose concurrent updates. Add synchronization or a compareExchange-loop!
    integers = copy;
}

public int read(int index) {
    return integers[index];
}
```

Comment: Java _does_ say something about the memory barriers of unrelated variables because `happens-before` closes over the program order.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you declare a variable `volatile` there is no guarantee that the thread will get the correct value. Volatile guarantees change in the variable is visible meaning instead of using the CPU cache it will write/read from main memory.
You will also need `synchronization` so that the reading thread does not read before the write is complete. Any reason for going with array rather than an ArrayList object because you are already using `Arrays.copyOf` and resizing?

Comment: Declaring an array as volatile marks the array-reference as volatile, but not the array-values.